# Swift Parse.com unable to retrieve object

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

So I am trying to get a String that is saved within an object from Parse.com. Here is the code that I am using to do so:

```
var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Replys")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("ipmdKB0N1N") {
        (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && object != nil {
            println(object)
            self.replyField.text = object["Replys"]
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
```

I want to make this string the text of the label called "replyField" but when I try to do that, Xcode gives an error like "Cannot assign value "AnyObject?" to type "String?"" Even when I add as! String, it still gives a similar (though not exactly the same) error. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should unwrap optional of `object`. Such as `object!["Replys"]` or `object?["Replys"]`

Like below:

```
self.replyField.text = object!["Replys"] as! String
```

or

```
self.replyField.text = object?["Replys"] as! String
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let replysString = object["Replys"] as! NSString
self.replyField.text = replysString as String
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it says that the type is not convertible to string

Comment: Is it stored as a string in the database?

Comment: Yes, the entire column is designated as a String type